# Binding entities to query parameters only allowed for entities have an identifier

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I am using a Symfony 4 project, and I want to change the user password, so I created a method in my repository and called it to the controller, but this error it diplay to me,

```
Binding entities to query parameters only allowed for entities that have an identifier.
```

**Repository**

```
  public function updateU($password,$email): ?Utilisateur
 {
   $dql = <<<DQL
 SELECT u
FROM App\Entity\Utilisateur u
WHERE u.email = :email
AND u.password = :password
DQL;

 return  $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql)
             ->setParameters(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])
             ->getSingleScalarResult();
```

}
**Controller**

```
/**
 * @Route("/Reset", name="Reset")
 * Method({"GET"})
 */
public function New(
    Request $request,
    UtilisateurRepository $URe,
    UserPasswordEncoderInterface $userPasswordEncoder,
    EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
    MailerInterface $mailer
) {
    $o = '';
    $Varmail = $_GET['email'];

    $user = new Utilisateur($o);
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
        ->add('password', PasswordType::class)
        ->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $to = $Varmail;
        $sujet = 'Password Changed';
        $Message = "Bonjour $Varmail Votre email est changé !";
        $pass = $user->setPassword(
            $userPasswordEncoder->encodePassword(
                $user,
                $form->get('password')->getData()
            )
        );

        $URe->updateU($pass, $Varmail);

        $Mai = new MailerController();
        $Mai->sendEmail($mailer, $to, $sujet, $Message);
    }
    return $this->render('modifier_mdp/index.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

How can i solve it , And Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your `updateU` method, you are making a request to get, not update the data. It's better to use the ObjectManager to save the data, since you still have a updated instance of the `Utilisateur` object in the `$user` variable.

```
   $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository(Event::class)->findOneBy(['email'=>$Varmail]);
   $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)->add('password', PasswordType::class)->getForm();
   if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
       // ...
       
       $user->setPassword(
           $userPasswordEncoder->encodePassword(
               $user,
               $form->get('password')->getData()
           )
       ); 
       
       // save Utilisateur with new password
       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
       $em->persist($user);
       $em->flush();
   }
```